# EDB File Format

Tags: .net, exchange-server, esent, edb

I want info about the Exchange Database EDB file format?

I have checked out the information provided in the following link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libesedb/files/

The documentation was good but quite confusing so I want some more help on it.

If some body has more info on EDB format then please provide it to me.

Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 6):

There's not much info out there, as you've found.  What you can do is have a look at the following three links, hopefully they'll cover everything you may still wish to learn:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310772.aspx - Information on the Extensible Storage Engine Architecture.
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683068%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx - Extensible Storage Engine Files; lists other file types associated with the Extensible storage engine.
- http://everything.explained.at/Extensible_Storage_Engine - Extensible Storage Engine Explained.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

As I am currently working on the Exchange EDB format I might could answer some question. I use libesedb as a basic source of information, but otherwise chose to access the EDB via the Extensible Storage Engine API (aka JetBlue, aka Esent API). So, if you can form some particular question I can try to answer it for you.

By the way as I see you using .net as a tag to this post I would like to point your attention to Laurion Burchall's Managed Esent API (open source). It reduces somewhat the cryptic complexity of the Windows API and might be useful for you to keep it "managed":
http://managedesent.codeplex.com/